# Hibernate mapping: ignore a super class field

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a class A and class B

```
public class A{
int f1;
int f2;
int f2;
}

public class B extends A{
}
```

my question is how to ignore a field for example 'f2', in the table mapped to B?

Comment: which inheritance strategy are you using?? table per class , table per subclass or table per concrete class..??

Comment: Did you read about transient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will try to answer assuming the edit I have made to your post is approved.
In the code below I am ignoring the field f2 from class A i.e. superclass of B using AttributeOverride.

```
@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name = "f2", column = @Column(name = "f2_col", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public class B extends A{
}
```

If you want to read about it further, refer to [AttributeOverride](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html).

AttributeOverride with `insertable = false`, `updatable = false` should help, but it also depends on your inheritance strategy. It just helps making mapped fields inherited from a superclass transient, so that some other subclass can use it but it will be ignored for this particular sub class.

Comment: @Amir thanks .. the edit was approved .. let me know if the solution works for you..

Comment: this just gives different name to the column in database table but the question is on how to ignore it, something similar to using Transient variable.

Comment: @Chaitanya thanks.. but assuming both  subclass and superclass are mapped and you want to ignore the **f2** value in subclass.. AttributeOverride with  _insertable = false, updatable = false_ should help.. but it also depends on your inheritance strategy .. it just helps making mapped field inherited from a superclass transient .. so that some other subclass can use it but it would ignore for this particular sub class.. let me know if my understanding is  wrong..

Comment: Thanks for explaining, now it makes sense to me :)

Comment: But even you mark a field `insertable` & `updatable` with `false`, Hibernate will expect such column in the Select statement!!! ...isn't it? so it's not really `transient` !

Answer (score 3):

If you want to conditionally apply fields to subclasses, maybe you should redesign your classes so that they look like this

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    // ...  
}

public class A extends MyAbstractClass {
    int f1;
}

public class B extends MyAbstractClass {
    int f2;
}
```

Assuming you're applying this to database table mappings with Hibernate, you could use [`@MappedSuperclass`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/mapping/MappedSuperclass.html) on MyAbstractClass and `@Entity` on A and B - hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot for pointing into @MappedSuperclass, you made my day!